# Wrapping created elements in a span

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I am trying to style our cookie policy banner but there is no HTML but only JS which generates the HTML.

I need to wrap both of the 'a' tags within a span but they are being created within a JS file.

Below is the JS snippet which is generating the 'a' tag.

```
function _createDismissLink(dismissText) {
    var dismissLink = document.createElement('a');
    _setElementText(dismissLink, dismissText);
  dismissLink.id = dismissLinkId;
  dismissLink.href = '#';
  dismissLink.style.marginLeft = '24px';
  return dismissLink;
}
```

I have tried to include a `dismissLink.wrap( "<span class='test'></span>" );`

But I've had no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

FOLLOWING ON FROM THIS

How would I go about wrapping this function and another function similar to it within a div?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dismissLink = document.createElement('a');
_setElementText(dismissLink, dismissText);
dismissLink.id = dismissLinkId;
dismissLink.href = '#';
dismissLink.style.marginLeft = '24px';

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(dismissLink);
return span;
```

Comment: Hi @Jagjeet - Would you happen to know how I would then wrap this function and another function similar within the same div? Thank you